comment-dwim inserting leading spaces in prog-mode
I started using yasnippet today, and was surprised with this buffer when using yas-new-snippet:
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
    # name: 
        # key: 
    # --

I could see there was nothing unusual with the variable that defined the initial buffer, so I decided to just add comments with comment-dwim, i.e., M-;. And this is what I get:
    #   |

The | indicates where the cursor is placed.
I would like to have prog-mode do this instead:
#   |

And not progressively indent comments at each newline, which is what it seems to be doing. Does anyone have some insight into this?
